# Best way to upgrade react-native to 0.60, copy components into a new project or change version on package.json?

Tags: react-native, upgrade

Not really a problem just yet, I have a project running in react-native and I would like to upgrade in the near future

Comment: have you check upgrade helper tool from react native https://github.com/react-native-community/upgrade-helper

Comment: I was recently in this situation. The upgrade tool below 0.59.9 is a pain the butt. So I generated a new project and copied over files. Took no longer than 20 mins.

Comment: The best way that works for me is to create a new project and move my source code to that.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking to take that route. I've noticed the upgrade tool is kinda painful

Comment: After a lot of pain with the upgrade tool I took the new-project and copy components route and I was done within 30 minutes, some settings had to be redone but each time the error messages helped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best (fastest) way is to create a new app and transfer your source files and dependencies.

Comment: I agree, after trying both ways I took that route

Comment: Just be careful of dependencies that don't autolink

Answer (score 1):

Start a new App takes care of a lot of unlinking problems as well

Answer (score 0):

1. Create new App using `react-native init` command
2. Copy all the packages from the old project

NOTE:: please dont ignore react-native unlink  whenever you run command react-native run-ios & pod install too, autolinking do work in 0.60 but still there might be changes than needs to be done in info.plist and appdelegate.m and in Xcode too

3. `yarn add @react-native-community/async-storage @react-native-community/datetimepicker @react-native-community/netinfo axios lodash moment react react-native react-native-animatable react-native-device-info react-native-dialog react-native-document-picker react-native-dropdown react-native-elements react-native-fast-image react-native-fbsdk react-native-firebase react-native-geocoder react-native-gesture-handler react-native-google-places-autocomplete react-native-google-signin react-native-image-crop-picker react-native-image-picker react-native-image-zoom-viewer react-native-maps-directions react-native-material-dropdown react-native-modal-wrapper react-native-progress react-native-searchable-dropdown react-native-simple-toast react-native-snap-carousel react-native-swipe-list-view react-native-swipeable-flat-list react-navigation react-redux redux redux-logger redux-persist redux-saga redux-thunk`
4. `react-native run-android`
5. see What went wrong and then remove that specific package from package.json and `yarn install`
   Repeat until and unless app:installDebug is called
6. even though app is install problem of fbsdk and more can occur resolve it using stackoverflow help
7. before installing those problematic packages to the project make sure those package are worth installing by verifying if those package are really used or commented out in your old project
   // "react-native-maps": "^0.26.1",
   // "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
   // "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0"
8. configure this app for IOS Note:: Andriod issue are very hard to solve. I haven't figure out till now Ill update when I find one for you. Sorry!!! :-p
9. bring your remaining files of old project to new project and replace App.js too
10. build your project `react-native run-ios`
    use `react-native start` and find the required packages and install them and change few codes using `yarn add` and vscode
11. likely, few changes will occured like async storage, react-navigation-tabs, react-navigation-stack etc react-native-safe-area-context react-native-screens react-native-reanimated @react-native-community/masked-view
12. Your app may run successfully but some ui and font issue may arrive which you will need to solve or dimiss it

I will be working to solve on android please share with me if you found one